# Static files not deploying to appspot via Eclipse

Tags: deployment, eclipse-plugin

I have a gwt app that contains some static image files.  I put them under "war/img" and everything works fine locally. I'm using Eclipse and use the deploy command to move everything over to the appspot server for deployment.

However, after I deploy the app to the appspot server in Eclipse, I get an error that the img directory doesn't exist.  It doesn't seem like it's being copied over.  I would do this manually if I could, but I don't know how to access appspot aside from the deploy command.

The strange thing is that this worked a month ago -- the static images were deploying just fine.